# Changing colour of substring from string in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I want to change color of a particular substring from a post.
eg:-

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tempor lacinia urna eget gravida.                      Quisque magna nulla, fermentum fermentum od
#keyword1 #keyword2 #keyword3 #keyword4 #keyword5

if above example is the post then i want to change the style of the keywords. I am using Next.js.

```
function handleBody(){
    var arr1=[],arr2=[];
    for(let i=0;i<post.body.length;i++){
        if(post.body[i]==="#"){
          arr1.push(i);
        }
        if(arr1.length!==arr2.length && post.body[i]==" " ){
            arr2.push(i);
        }
    }
    for(let i=0;i<post.body.length;i++){
      const trial2 =  post.body.substring(arr1[i], arr2[i])
      const trial =  post.body.substring(arr1[i], arr2[i]).style.color ="blue";

      post.body.replace(trial2, trial)
    }
    return post.body
  }
```

I have tried as above but its giving an error

> TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'color')

Comment: What is `post`?

Comment: `post.body.substring()` will return a `string`. Strings are not DOM elements, and does not have DOM properties like `style`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set style of a `string` type... which isn't possible, instead you can wrap the substrings in a `span`, here is a more optimized function for what you want to do.

```
function handleBody() {
  let body = post.body;
  let keywords = body.match(/#[^\s]+/g); // extract all hashtags

  if (!keywords) {
    // no keywords found, return original body
    return body;
  }

  // wrap each keyword in a span with a class or style
  keywords.forEach(keyword => {
    body = body.replace(keyword, `<span style="color: blue">${keyword}</span>`);
  });

  return body;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to change styles for something that is not an HTML element.

You can use regex to select the words that begin with '#' and then replace them with a `span` containing the word.

Then you can change the color of the content of the span with CSS or with JS.

Here is an example:

```js
let postBody = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tempor lacinia urna eget gravida. Quisque magna nulla, fermentum fermentum od #keyword1 #keyword2 #keyword3 #keyword4 #keyword5'

const regex = /#[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g;
const color = "blue";

postBody = postBody.replace(regex, `<span style="color: ${color}">$&</span>`)

document.getElementById('postBody').innerHTML = postBody
```

```html
<div id="postBody"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`post.body.substring()` will return a `string`. Strings are not DOM elements, and does not have DOM properties like `style`

In order to change the color of any substrings in your text, you would need to wrap them in an element tag, such as `<span>`. You could then add a style or className to these span elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this library, is does exactly what you are expecting. It matches a regex pattern and style the way you want. It has some predefined patterns and you can create your own.

Lets say that your keywords are wrapped in square brackets or curly brackets, like this:

```
const text = "this is your text and this is [#keyword1] and [#keyword2];
```

after installing the library using

```
npm install react-substring-styler
or
yarn add react-substring-styler
```

You can wrap your text like this

```
   <ParsedText pattern={[{
      type: "squareBrackets",
      style: {
        color: "purple",
      }]}>{text}
   </ParsedText>
```